# Display text with one word appearing after another word effect

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-animation

I want to display a label or uitextview with text in a manner that text will appear slowly with one word at a time. I mean first it will display first word then second and then third and so on…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with core-animations, but this could be acheived by using a simple NSTimer and on each interval append the UILabel's text

Comment: Your suggestion is great but I will prefer to display each word with effect e.g appearing in light gray color and then gradually changing color to black.

Comment: i will be using your suggestion if I could not find any solution.. thanks for replying